# What is the motivation behind sigma-algebra properties?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, soft-question

Sigma algebras are the fundamental construct that probability theory and Lebesgue integration are based on. I learned a few monographs in probability theory where the term of "sigma-algebra" shows up as a definition, utilitarian, without any discussion around it.

I wonder:

1. How people came to that construct? I mean how people came to the properties that describe a sigma-algebra.
2. Why the properties of sigma-algebra are so unique in conjunction so that they got a special name in math?

There is a similar question on math.stackexchange was raised before but it does not have a clear explanation.

If you know books or internet-resources that shed light on the subject please let me know.

Comment: The motivation for $\sigma$ - algebras is to define a family of sets to serve as the domain for a measure $\mu$. It this sense it is clear that the set itself should be measurable, and the empty set should be measurable. Also, if we know the measure of $X$ and the measure of $A \subseteq X$, then $A^{\complement}$ should have measure $\mu(X) - \mu(A)$. Furthermore, one would want to be able to approximate the measure of a set by others i.e. if $\mu(A_i)$ is known for every $i$ in some countable index set, then the measure of $\cup A_i$ should exist and be known in some sense or another.

Comment: Note, however, that $\sigma$-algebra is not the only widely used domain of measures. $\sigma$-rings and Dynkin-Systems are also suitable - and they have similar properties. So I'm not sure if the properties of $\sigma$-algebras are really that special.

Comment: @G.Chiusole: I suggest you answer in the "answer" box and not in the "comment" box.

Comment: Fair point, I figured it was a very incomplete, vague "answer".

Comment: Still an answer, and a valid one in my opinion.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1420386/why-countable-unions-intersections-etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The motivation for $\sigma$- algebras is to define a family of sets to serve as the domain for a measure $\mu$. It this sense it is clear that the set itself should be measurable, and the empty set should be measurable. Also, if we know the measure of X and the measure of $A \subseteq X$, then $X\setminus A$ should have measure $\mu(X) - \mu(A)$. Furthermore, one would want to be able to approximate the measure of a set by others i.e. if $\mu(A_i)$ is known for every $i$ in some countable index set, then the measure of $\cup A_i$ should exist and be known in some sense or another.

On the other hand one wants to exclude paradoxical examples like Banach-Tarski, so one cannot have a every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ be measurable. For exmaple, if the index set before were allowed to be uncountable, then every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ would be measurable and the theory would not behave as one would like.

Also, note that $\sigma$- algebras are not the only widely used domain of measures. $\sigma$ -rings and Dynkin-Systems are also suitable - and they have similar properties. So I'm not sure if the properties of $\sigma$-algebras are really that special.

Comment: thank you. What would you advise for further reading?

Comment: Firstly, hands down: Wikipedia. Secondly, I like the ones suggested [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11591/suggestions-for-a-good-measure-theory-book)

Comment: thank you. There are plenty. Which would you personally suggest suitable enough as the first course?

Comment: [Measure and Integral](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783319153643) by Brokate and Kersting is suitable for beginners, though I am not sure into how much detail they go regarding different types of domains for measures

Answer (score 7):

Regarding probability theory, the $\sigma$-algebra definition tries to acknowledge the fact that if you want to be able to ask about the probability of events $A_1, A_2, \ldots$, you might also want to ask about the probability of one of them ($A_k$) not taking place (that is, $A_k^C$); or at least one taking place, which is
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k;$$
or all of them occurring, as in
$$\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty A_k;$$
or none, which is
$$\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right)^C=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k^C;$$
and so on.

Then, when you realize that for this *reasonable* list of events you want to consider, you just need to ask for certain specific properties that the family of events need to satisfy, you get the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: thank you. What would you suggest as a definitive reading on the subject? Suitable for a beginner.