# What is a $\sigma$-algebra, really?

Tags: probability-theory, intuition, motivation

I know that a $\sigma$-algebra is a suitable generalization of the notion of *sample space*, in the following sense:

> Consider a sample space $\Omega$ and a collection $\mathscr{F}$ of subsets of $\Omega$.  Then $\mathscr{F}$ is called a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ if the following are satisfied:
> (1) $\phi \in \mathscr{F}$.  (2)  If $A \in \mathscr{F}$, then $A^C \in \mathscr{F}$, that is, complementation is closed.  (3)  If $\{A_i\}$ is a sequence in $\mathscr{F}$, then $\bigcup_i{A_i} \in \mathscr{F}$, that is, countable union is closed.

I would like to know what motivated this definition for a $\sigma$-algebra, in simple terms.

Comment: from what I understand, probability was concerned with being able to do 3 operations: taking unions, taking intersections, having complements and having both the empty set and the whole set as well or a σ-algebra. Properties of measuring also wanted these properties. So it logically follows that you wanted a collection of sets for with which measure axioms will work much like group axioms.

Comment: this may not address your exact question, but it is interesting I think : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555450

Comment: Thank you for that link, @311411!  =)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the motivation behind sigma-algebra properties?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564422/what-is-the-motivation-behind-sigma-algebra-properties)

Comment: Borel field in measure theory plays a very similar role.

Comment: @311411:  I think your first link addresses my question better than the second link.  =)

Comment: My professor of measure theory told us that in the past an attempt was made to build a theory in which (3) only permitted a finite union... the result was an unsatisfactory theory.

Comment: Are finite algebras not automatically $\sigma$-algebras, then, @311411?

Comment: I think that is correct; not automatically. Your property (3) is the crucial part of (1), (2) and (3).

Comment: I generally think of the $\sigma$-algebra as the information you have, i.e. an event $A \in \mathcal F$ means that $\mathcal F$ has the information on whether $A$ occurred.  In that sense, the last two properties are intuitive.  (2) says if you know whether $A$ occurred, you also know whether $A$ didn't occur.  (3) is then so intuitive that it sounds like a tautology written in words: it says that you know whether or not any individual $A_i$ occurred, you know whether or not any of the $A_i$ occurred.