# What motivated the use of $\sigma$-algebras in measure theory (or probability)?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, axioms

In the definition of a measure space (or a probability space), the measurable sets are required to form a $\sigma$-algebra. That is, they must be closed under complements and countable unions (and thus countable intersections). Does anyone know why these closure properties were chosen?

I see a good argument for closure under complements: if the entire space has measure $r\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\cup\{\infty\}$, we would like $\mu(A^C)=r-\mu(A)$. I also see a good argument for closure under **disjoint** unions (and perhaps countable disjoint unions), since we would like $\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)$, when $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

However, I'm not clear why we assume closure under countable unions or intersections (or even finite ones) . If we think of non-measurable sets as pathological, is there a reason to expect that the union and intersection of two non-pathological sets will be non-pathological?

EDIT: The first answer points out that a family of sets is a $\sigma$-algebra if and only if it is a $\lambda$-system **and** it is (or is generated by) a $\pi$-system (by Dynkin's theorem). Since we already have arguments for why measurable sets should form a $\lambda$-system, the original question can be considered equivalent to: "why do we assume measurable sets form a $\pi$-system"?

Comment: You want to be able to measure as many sensibly defined sets as possible, but asking for uncountable unions may be too much, so take a small step back from that. There is no practical difference between countable disjoint unions and countable unions

Comment: This is known as a Dynkin system, which is useful for generating sigma algebras. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system

and here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733983/sigma-algebra-requirement-3-closed-under-countable-unions

By itself you won't be able to measure all possible intersections and unions of the sets therein, which is a necessary for defining measurable sets and measures.

Comment: @Henry I see. So, are you saying that we assume closure under countable unions because doing so is useful and doesn't seem to cause any problems? I disagree that there is no practical difference between unions and disjoint unions, since there is always an obvious way to assign measure to a disjoint union (in terms of the measures of the individual sets), and this is not the case for unions in general.

Comment: If I have a countable set of measurable sets $\{A_n\}$ then I can let $B_n = A_n \cap \left(\bigcup\limits_{i<n} B_i\right)^c= \left(A_n^c \cup \left(\bigcup\limits_{i<n} B_i\right)\right)^c$ using finite unions and complements. Then the $B_n$ are all distinct and  $\bigcup\limits_{n} A_n = \bigcup\limits_{n} B_n$.  If you would be happy with $\mu\left(\bigcup\limits_{n} B_n\right)=\sum\limits_n \mu\left(B_n\right)$ then it seems reasonable to say $\mu\left(\bigcup\limits_{n} A_n\right)$ is also this.

Comment: @Henry That makes sense, but it requires assuming closure under intersections (to define $B_n$), which is equivalent to assuming closure under unions (assuming complements). In other words, the same question of "why do we assume closure under unions" applies equally well to intersections. I'm going to edit the question to point this out.

Comment: For say a probability measure to be useful, if I have two measurable events $X$ and $Y$, I at least want to be able to ask what is $\mathbb P(X^c)$, the probability event $X$ does not happen, and what is $\mathbb P(X \cup Y)$, the probability at least one of the events happens, and what is $\mathbb P(X \cap Y)$, the probability both events happen.  So if you have a measure which is not closed under finite unions or intersections or complements then it would be of less practical use.

Comment: @Henry Interesting, so you're saying that the motivation for using $\sigma$-algebras is that complements, unions and intersections are needed in most applications of probability/measure theory. In other words, it is an extrinsic justification, rather than an intrinsic one (intrinsic meaning something based on the concepts of probability, length, area or volume). That had been my original guess, but I wasn't sure if I had the whole picture.

Answer (score 1):

You want these intuitive properties for a probability:

1. The probability of a countable union of disjoints events is the sum of it probabilities.
2. The probability of the complementary event is the "complementary probability".

These two properties essentially defines a probability function over a collection of sets. A collection of sets that is closed under complementation and countable union of disjoint sets is called a $ \lambda $-system (it is also called a Dynkin system).

But it can be shown that the induced $\lambda $-system over a collection of sets that is already closed by finite intersections defines a $\sigma$-algebra. This theorem is called sometimes as the $ \lambda -\pi$ theorem (because a system closed by finite intersections is called a $\pi$-system).

Because its natural to ask by the probability of the intersection of events (that is, the event that represent that two events happens "at the same time"), or it union (that is: if at least one of them happen) then its natural to define a $ \sigma $-algebra and a probability function such that the two previous properties at the top of this answer holds. Then everything follows naturally from there.

Comment: So, if the measurable sets are generated by a $\pi$-system using complements and countable unions, then it doesn't matter if those unions are disjoint or arbitrary (by the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem). In other words, the measurable sets form a $\sigma$-algebra if and only if they form a $\pi$-system AND a $\lambda$-system. We both agree that there are natural reasons for assuming that they form a $\lambda$-system. So, your answer shows that the original question is equivalent to the question "why do we assume that measurable sets form (or are generated by) a $\pi$-system"?  Very helpful; thanks!