# Show $\nu(B)=\mu(A\cap B)$ is a measure

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

[image]

First step is to show that $A\cap B\in\mathcal A$, which is not obvious from the definition of $\sigma$-field that I have: (1) $\mathcal X, \emptyset\in \mathcal A$, (2) $A\in \mathcal A\Rightarrow A^c\in\mathcal A$, (3) $A_1,A_2,\dots\in\mathcal A;A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset \forall i\ne j\Rightarrow \bigcup _{n=1}^\infty A_n\in\mathcal A$.

For this I drew a venn diagram but it ultimately boils down to these steps: Because $\mathcal A$ is closed under complement and union,$(A^c\cup B)^c=A\cap B^c \in\mathcal A$. Then $(A\cap B^c)\cup A^c=\mathcal X\cap (B^c\cup A^c)=B^c\cup A^c\in\mathcal A$, so $(B^c\cup A^c)^c=A\cap B\in\mathcal A$.

Since $A\cap B\in\mathcal A$ and $\mu$ is a measure, $\nu(B)=\mu(A\cap B)\in[0,\infty]$ for all $B$. This is the first condition for measure.

Second condition is measure of infinite union of disjoint sets becomes infinite sum of measures, i.e. $$\begin{split}\nu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n\right)&=\mu\left(A\cap\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n\right)\\
&=\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (A\cap B_n)\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu\left(A\cap B_n\right)&&\text{bc $B_n$ are disjoint, $A\cap B_n\in\mathcal A$, and $\mu$ is a measure}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu(B_n)\end{split}$$

which holds.

Is it right? Maybe there is a shorter way of showing $A\cap B\in\mathcal A$.

Comment: To show that $A \cap B \in \mathcal A$, you can simply observe that $A \cap B = (A^c \cup B^c)^c$. The rest looks fine.

Comment: Are you sure your definition of $\sigma$-field is correct? Yours is the same as the usual definition except it replaces closure under countable union with closure under countable disjoint union.

Comment: Agree with @Mason, this definition is not equivalent unless you add another hypothesis that $\mathcal A$ is closed under finite (not necessarily disjoint) unions. Your definition doesn't include this, so all you get is a Dynkin system (aka $\lambda$-system). See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/733991/169852) for more details.

Comment: @Bungo Thank you! That is much shorter. And my definition is definitely not correct, I mixed up the $\sigma$-field definition with the definition of a measure. I mean, the definition I'm referencing is correct, but I copied it down wrong.

Comment: @Mason thank you for catching that! I must've mixed up the disjoint part of the definition of a measure with the $\sigma$-field definition.